# JAX-WS Client Soap Message Inserting Blank Namespace on Nested Nodes

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws, java-ee-6

I am having an issue with how JAX-WS (Java 1.6) is generating the soap messages to send to the remote server.  I used the WSDL Import to generate all the necessary classes but noticed that when the SOAP Message is send to the server it inserts a xmlns="" and a xmlns:ns2="http://somexmlnamespace" on a nested node like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body xmlns="http://somexmlnamespace">
      <ParentNode xmlns="http://somexmlnamespace">
         <ChildNode xmlns="" xmlns:ns2="http://somexmlnamespace">
         </ChildNode>
      </ParentNode>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The blank xmlns="" is causing issues with the service I'm trying to connect to.  If I manually post the message without it:

```
<ChildNode xmlns:ns2="http://somexmlnamespace">
         </ChildNode>
```

the soap message response is what I expect it to be. How would I go about having Java not send the xmlns=""?  Is there a modification in the generated classes in the XML annotations or would a message handler fix this?

Comment: paste the code generated specifically to this part, I think there should be something that point to the namespace, are you using wsdl2import, jaas, or which tool to create the client ?

Answer (score 0):

In parentNode class add the below to getChildNode() method:-@XmlElement(namespace="http://somexmlnamespace")

Assuming ChildNode is in namespace http://somexmlnamespace due to xmlns specified in ParentNode.

I have assumed JAXB. If this does not answer as @Koitoer has said provide your generated code.